# Math.random não é aleatório o suficiente

Tags: javascript

Eu reparei que se eu usar o `Math.random` com valores de 0 a 10, é muito possível que o resultado se repita ou gere um valor aproximado do anterior.

Por exemplo, eu executei:

```js
function random() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
```

e saiu:

[image: Math.random não tão aleatório]

Se existir, como eu faço para gerar valores ainda mais aleatórios?

Comment: Baseado em quê você afirma que Math.random() não é suficientemente aleatório? Afirmações fortes como essa pedem provas fortes. Que testes fez, além de imprimir meia dúzia de amostras? Qual implementação de Javascript você está testando e afirma ser ruim?

Comment: bom, para o que eu estou tentando fazer, realmente não é, botei a função ``random`` lá em cima para você testar. Não estou dizendo que é ruim, eu só quero evitar que numeros repetidos sejam exibidos com menos frequência, pois quanto menor o numeri máximo, maior a probabilidade de se repetir com frequência

Comment: Da forma que você fez, só vai gerar números entre 0 e 9, então claro que depois de poucas execuções vai ter repetição, e quanto mais vezes executar, mais chances de repetir. O que exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: queria ter uma variação maior maior caso executasse novamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como descreveu: "...é muito possível que o resultado se repita ou gere um valor aproximado do anterior.", há explicações do porquê [não há como um computador gerar números verdadeiramente aleatórios](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124233/why-is-it-impossible-to-produce-truly-random-numbers#:%7E:text=The%20problem%20with%20a%20computer,(such%20as%20exact%20time)). E como o *range* de números que exemplificou é pequeno, é *esperado que uma variação entre eles seja menor, dado que a chance de cair um mesmo número, depois do anterior, ainda é a mesma dentro de 0 a 10*.

Você pode aumentar o limite deles (substituindo o valor máximo por 100) e fazer uma implementação como a especificada na [documentação da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random): `Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(100));` para obter uma variação maior. Na documentação mencionada também é explicado [como gerar números aleatórios com maior segurança](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues).

Recomendo pesquisar mais a respeito sobre números gerados de forma aleatória por computadores.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada

Comment: Então não há nada que eu possa fazer... Mesmo assim, obrigado por esclarecer. Eu até tentei usar varios randoms e fazer a média, mas parece que reduziu mais ainda a aleatoriedade.

Comment: Até concordo com dizer que "há explicações do porquê não há como um computador gerar números verdadeiramente aleatórios", mas não acredito que isto tenha relação com o problema  do autor (sequer existe um problema demonstrado, de fato). Edit: isto não é um problema na resposta, só deixei como observação no sentido de o autor da pergunta não associar indevidamente a percepção com a explicação do link.

Comment: Sim, @Bacco, tem razão. Inseri ela apenas por considerar pertinente ao assunto abordado na pergunta, junto com uma demonstração de como "diminuir a aleatoriedade" (e realmente, não há um _problema_ de fato relatado na pergunta).